# Site is suddenly not apearing for main Keyword on google no errors can be found

Tags: seo, google, google-search, googlebot

My site: www.lovespells24.com ist suddenly not showing up on google for its main keyword " love spells". It has been consistently on page 5 and 6 and today can't be found, I checked multiple times all pages, nothing.

Webmaster tools show no errors, the site is white hat no spam links that I would know about. Can someone please help? Why is it not showing up anymore?

It is not even found on the last pages, its simply gone. It is indexed, when I type in the url it shows my site.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In 1st step you should   check  Google Search Console messages  (maybe there is something wrong with your site , penalty from google for example , etc )

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home

Comment: There are no errors, I have checked this.

Comment: There are also no penalties, the site is white hat, spam score is 0 and DA 23 PA 33 there is nothing wrong with the site that I would know.

Comment: if all is ok in google search console , then you should  wait 2-3 days . It's a good chance  that  there is google algorithm update in progress (and you see so called  "google dance" )